# get resource is null

Tags: java

I have an `@Test` method with invocationCount=3.

Each time this method is run, there is a call for preparing some doc into another method.

All it's working GREAT when the `@Test` is run for the 1st time.

The doc is succesfully found and loaded:

```
final DocumentRegistryResource documentRegistryResource = 
    RestClientFactory.getInstance().createDocumentRegistryResource(
        getUserRestAuth());
final File importFile = new File(
    this.getClass().getResource("/documents-template-test.xml").getFile());
```

BUT, at the 2nd and 3rd invocation, i receive a null exception:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/documents-template-test.xml")
```

is no longer found.

Can anyone explain me WHY? The original file is on the same place, nothing was moved
during the 1st time invocation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you close your file in the cleanup phase? Otherwise, your file might be locked on the second invocation of your test.

Also, be careful with the use of the `final` keyword combined with a test case. Using `static` or `final` can break a correct initialization or cleanup.

Comment: You were right. The file was locked due to other operations applied to it. Thanks.